# will split mongodb collection into multiple collections improve query speed?

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have a very big collection, it has `17369150` records now, I query by `_id` very frequently.

I am considering if I split the big collection into 64 by some rules for example split by `_id[0:2] % 64`, **can I improve the query speed by this?**

One thing I am sure for now is that if I query some _id that **does not exist** in collection, this query will make other query slow.

Comment: do you use sharding ?

Comment: what do you mean `sharding `?

Comment: [MongoDB Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/)

Comment: Don't you already have another open question [mongodb query very slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36588474/5031275) which much like this could also do with some clarification on what you are actually doing? I think it would be better for you to add the details of what the query and purpose actually is there, instead of basically ask the same question. And again with not enough detail for a reasonable answer.

Comment: @BlakesSeven yes, you are right, I am going to delete that question. In fact my question is simple now, I just find query by `_id` is slow, so I am thinking split this collection

Comment: @kiro112 so `Sharding is a method for storing data across multiple machines.`, for just now I just have one machine, so I am thinking I split the collection into 64 collections.

Comment: I think you best get to "explaining" on "this question" even if you do. This is far too-broad as there are way too many answers. And honestly if going to multiple "instances" ( which is actually different from "machines" ) is not an option for you, then this is all about *"what is your query actually doing"*, which is the complete omission from your question and therefore not answerable by anything reputable or worthwhile.

Comment: @BlakesSeven `what is your query actually doing` do you mean you want to know this: I am iterator `jd_all_vect.jd_vect`, then I find record in `jd_all_raw.jd_raw` by `_id`, the latter is slow and I think it is because the collection is too big

Comment: I mean **[edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36589380/edit)** to something that actually tells us more than *"can I improve the query speed by this"* or *"if I query some _id that does not exist"* which are both next to useless statements without any code to demonstrate.